# How to add Firefox to Dock?

Tags: release-freya, plank, firefox

I installed Firefox by doing this:

```
 1. wget
    https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/42.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-42.0.tar.bz2
 2. tar -xjvf firefox-42.0.tar.bz2
 3. sudo rm -rf /opt/firefox*
 4. sudo mv firefox /opt/firefox
 5. sudo ln -sf /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

When I run it on terminal, the only option that I have when right click on Firefox's icon on Dock is "Close". How can I add Firefox to Dock?

Comment: Why aren't you installing firefox from official repositories by typing 
`sudo apt-get install firefox` into terminal or by installing from software center?

Comment: @Rafael, it was a bad idea indeed. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get an icon on plank (and in slingshot) an app needs to have a corresponding .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/`.
The desktop file also handles MimeTypes and lets you specify additional menu options (such as 'Open New Window' etc.)

Note: If you install firefox from the apt repositories with `sudo apt-get install firefox` it will update to v42 and the desktop file will be created for you. Since you have already installed it by other means, [here](http://pastebin.com/FzL7189h) is the *firefox.desktop* file it includes.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me. I added the firefox.desktop file to `~/.local/share/applications`